# Beginner react project, npm start not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I am currently learning React. I have made a react project using the command line by typing: `$ npx create-react-app myreactapp` After this is complete, I cd into my directory and run `$ npm start`. I then get the following error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactpractice@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactpractice@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-30T16_54_23_700Z-debug.log
```

I have tried things like deleting package-lock.json and all the node modules and then trying npm install, however this hasn't worked. Here is my log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\matthew_vidovic\\Documents\\Node.js\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\matthew_vidovic\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.7
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle reactpractice@0.1.0~prestart: reactpractice@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle reactpractice@0.1.0~start: reactpractice@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle reactpractice@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle reactpractice@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\Documents\reactpractice\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\Documents\Node.js\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\composer;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Enterprise Backup 8.0\\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\AppData\Local\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\Documents\VisualStudio\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\Documents\PHP;C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
9 verbose lifecycle reactpractice@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\Documents\reactpractice
10 silly lifecycle reactpractice@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle reactpractice@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle reactpractice@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: reactpractice@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid reactpractice@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\matthew_vidovic\Documents\reactpractice
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\matthew_vidovic\\Documents\\Node.js\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\matthew_vidovic\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.7
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error reactpractice@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the reactpractice@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT*****
I have just figured out that if I run `$ npm run eject` and then try `$ npm start` it works. Why is this? What does npm run eject do?

Answer (score 0):

Same error faced by me. I solved it by reinitiating the app. I think this cause because of not properly installation of node modules. As it is the start of the project, the best method is to recreate the app.
Thanks.